# I'm trying to remove the beta version from Blend 4 and VS 2010 phone tools application it fail

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

When I try to install the new phone tool application, it requires me to remove the previous beta version in order starting with phone developer tools beta. so go to control panel uninstalll I click on tit it gives me an error. "a problem has been encountered while loading the set up components. canceling set up" Anyone help please. thank

Answer (score 1):

This happened with my VS 2010 Beta. I used [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) and removed all file/registry entries and then installed the latest version of VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things get a bit messed up when installing and uninstalling lots of ctps. Try this uninstall/reinstall sequence for anything that might be getting in the way.

Known Good March -> April CTP Un/Install Sequence